# How to convert from HH:MM:SS to hour decimal?

Tags: c#, format

i have a string like this

```
currentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

How do i convert it to hour in decimal? 
For example : 00:30:00  = 0.5 hour
Thank you.

Comment: `ts.TotalHours` (which returns `double`; if you want `decimal` - cast it: `(decimal) (ts.TotalHours)`)

Comment: Look at `TimeSpan`

Comment: `decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(TimeSpan.Parse("11:30").TotalHours);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TotalHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.7.2) which gives a the time in hours as a double.  You can just cast it to decimal.

```
decimal hours = (decimal) ts.TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan.TotalHours`. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional hours.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Define an interval of 1 day, 15+ hours.
      TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
      Console.WriteLine("Value of TimeSpan: {0}", interval);

      Console.WriteLine("{0:N5} hours, as follows:", interval.TotalHours);
      Console.WriteLine("   Hours:        {0,3}", 
                        interval.Days * 24 + interval.Hours);
      Console.WriteLine("   Minutes:      {0,3}", interval.Minutes);
      Console.WriteLine("   Seconds:      {0,3}", interval.Seconds);
      Console.WriteLine("   Milliseconds: {0,3}", interval.Milliseconds);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Value of TimeSpan: 1.15:42:45.7500000
//       39.71271 hours, as follows:
//          Hours:         39
//          Minutes:       42
//          Seconds:       45
//          Milliseconds: 750
```

Example with your code

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Parse("00:30:00");
        var ts = now.TimeOfDay; // ts is your timespan
        Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalHours); // will print 0.5
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dKKkpe)

`TotalHours` is a double (which is a kind of decimal). If you want a decimal because you need a decimal, you can do `(decimal)ts.TotalHours`. Before doing so, take the time to look online the difference between double and decimal to see if you really need a decimal.